# All divs are not coming while parsing html by dom file

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to parse all divs by using DOM file but all the divs are not coming.

My code is:

```
<?php
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ebay.in');
foreach($html->find('div') as $element) 
       echo $element->class . '<br>';   
?>
```

Comment: Maybe there's an error in the HTML markup that's causing it.

Comment: I had simply added simple_html_dom.php file which i had downloaded from net

Comment: Try a local file first, is `$html` returning anything?

Comment: Yes if i write Echo $html then the full ebay site is opening

Comment: Try using PHP built-in DOM manipulation extension, DOMDocument, in particular [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) which enables you to retrieve what you want with this simple query `//div`.